# How to integrate Stripe Payment Gateway in localhost?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment-gateway, localhost

I want to install stripe payment gateway in my localhost, for my testing purpose. Is there any way exists to download stripe payment extension for testing purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about downloading in the localhost, but I found this video a useful tutorial for integrating Stripe  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoUBLxKa0pQ

Comment: Thanks for your response, In this video he got Strip Payment from Magenest. They are not providing any trial version for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Stripe official Magento 2 extension:

> Stripe Payments
>   https://marketplace.magento.com/stripeofficial-stripe-payments.html

install Magento 2 extension as root:

```
cd /home/magento/shop/
su $(stat -c '%U' index.php) -s /bin/bash
composer require stripe/stripe-php
composer require stripeofficial/stripe-payments
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download the Stripe payment extension for testing purposes: https://marketplace.magento.com/magenest-module-stripe-global.html

All the instructions and documents you can check in the developer documentation.